# C#/ASP.NET Custom Permissions to Perform Specifc Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I'm building an web application that I want users to have specific permissions to perform a specific action. I don't want to use the default permission and role providers in ASP.NET.

I was thinking of having each User associated with a Role. Each Role is mapped to a set of Permissions (CreatePost, ReadPost, UpdatePost, DeletePost and so on).

I have a couple of questions regarding this. Would it be best to have a boolean property for each Permission on the role or some sort of bitfield? I like the idea of having methods for this but properly need to map these to the permissions stored for the role in the database.

Also, how would I implement this for each action/request? I'm thinking something along the lines of what was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474507/asp-net-mvc-check-if-user-can-perform-action) but I'm not really sure.

Thanks!

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Why don't you want to use the Role provider to do this?  What need do you have that it conflicts with?

Comment: @casperOne: It's a very large scale enterprise application that I don't really want to override methods and have throw NotImplementedException... it's not very nice in my opinion. I really want a custom solution so that we have complete control over everything.

Comment: The fact that it is a large-scale application is really a red herring, it's not relevant to why one would or wouldn't use the RoleProvider.  Also, it's easier to do the coding up front for the custom RoleProvider *now* than have to sprinkle method calls *everywhere* in your code that you want to provide security (as opposed to just adding an attribute).  Especially for a large-scale application, it's self-defeating to **not** go this way.

Comment: @casperOne: Sure using the Role provider is nice, but I don't like the idea of specifying the "Role" on each page. I like the idea of using specific permissions. 

Example: I will create roles that have access to A, B, C, and D. And then another role that has access to A, B, C but NOT D. I don't want to have to hard code Roles into my code. I just want "does this user have permissions for this?" to check the user's associated role's permissions.

This is something I find RoleProvider doesn't provide for my use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own role provider and register it in the web.config. Look at the MSDN for a sample. Once it is registered it will associate the roles you provide with the principal.

I've just done that for one of my project and it works fine.

To check whether the user has permission to execute a task you'll have to see whether the user is in the required role. In "normal" ASP.NET you will have to do this in code. In MVC you can do that with attributes on each class/method in the controller.

Comment: "In 'normal' ASP.NET you will have to do this in code." - this is not true.  Have a look at the PrincipalPermissionAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx) The default Membership API provider hooks into CAS, and so can your custom provider.

Comment: The biggest problem with using ASP.NET providers is that you have to override a lot of members. Also if I don't use a specific method, I have to throw a NotImplementedException() which isn't very nice in my opinion.

How could I use custom attributes and have my own role implementation without using the Role Provider?

Comment: True, in most cases (membership and profile providers) the implementation is littered with NotImplementedExceptions. However, the RoleProvider has not so many methods and there fore only the methods that cereate, delete, and change the roles will return NotImplementedExceptions, which IMHO makes it worth using it. The problem is that if you do not use the RoleProvider it is quite difficult to attach the roles to the pricipal created by the authentication of ASP.NET.

Comment: see my post above to @casperOne regarding my permission "inheritance" issue. Essentially I don't want to have to hard code "Roles" in the code. I want it to be "does user have permission to do this action?". They would get their permission *because* they are a memeber of a specific role.